# Latex-suite vim-latex automatic recompilation of file when modified

Tags: vim-latex

I've installed [vim-latex (aka latex-suite)](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net) ViM plugin and started to customize it. One thing I cannot find is the ability to perform an automatic recompilation every time the `.tex` file I'm editing is written on disk (i.e. every time I use the command `:w` of ViM). It would be very useful to me as I use `zathura` to view the pdf and it supports automatic detection of changes and it displays the updated pdf file.

Does anyone know how to achieve this effect with that plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which command would you use to start a compilation otherwise? You can put something like the following in your `.vimrc`: `autocmd BufWritePost *.tex <compilation command>`, with `<compilation command>` replaced by the command starting your compilation. But instead of doing this, I use a custom mapping to save the file, which also runs `make`: `nmap <leader>m :up<cr>:make<cr>`, you could customize this to run your compilation command with `nmap <leader>m :up<cr><compilation command>`.

Comment: To compile I use the shortcut `\ll` provided by vim-latex. Are there any ways to simply execute the command `\ll` every time I write? Something like `autocmd BufWritePost *.tex <press \ll>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard binding used by the vim-latexsuite `\ll` does `call Tex_RunLaTeX()`. If you want VIM to do something every time after a file is written, you can use the `autocmd BufWritePost`, you can then give a filepattern that has to be matched by the written file to limit the scope of that `autocmd`, e.g., `*.tex` and then call functions of VIM. So you could put the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.tex call Tex_RunLaTeX()
```

If you don't want this to happen *every* time you save a file, it might be a good idea to create a custom binding that does save your file (if necessary) and then calls the function that runs LaTeX, e.g., you could use:

```
nmap <leader>m :up<cr>:call Tex_RunLaTeX()<cr>
```

This would create a mapping in normal mode that updates the file (so writes if there were changes) and after updating calls `Tex_RunLaTeX()`. With your current configuration that mapping would be on `\m` (`<leader>` is a configurable key, that is used for many bindings, it defaults to a backslash, you can change the `<leader>` by using `let mapleader="<whatever>"`, that would also affect the bindings of vim-latexsuite).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works fine! Just a question: is there a way to avoid ViM showing the standard output of the command? I tried modifying your command into `nmap <leader>m :up<cr>:silent call Tex_RunLaTeX()<cr>` but it does not work.

Comment: @LuxGiammi if `silent` doesn't work, I don't know.